# Set default v-model when using vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

So I got this input, but I want to set email from computed state as v-model. I am already using $v.emaill.$model from vuelidate, is there way to set default v-model?

html
`input.form-control(v-model="$v.emaill.$model", type="text")`

```js
validations: {
    emaill: {
      email,
      required,
      isUnique(value) {
        if (_.isEmpty(value)) {
          return false;
        }
        if (this.profile.email === value){
          return true;
        }else{
          return api.auth.emailTaken({
            email: this.emaill,
          });
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I think you might not be using vuelidate correctly. You aren't meant to use $v as model, it just contains the current error status of your validations and a couple of methods (e.g. $touch) which you can call to manually kick off the validation if necessary.

instead you'd do this:

```
<input v-model="email" type="text">

...

<script>
export default {
  validations: {
    emaill: {
      email,
      required,
      isUnique(value) {
        if (_.isEmpty(value)) {
          return false;
        }
        if (this.profile.email === value) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return api.auth.emailTaken({
            email: this.emaill,
          });
        }
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      emaill: "",
    };
  },
};
```

Vuelidate monitors the 'emaill' field in data. You can afterwards check the validation and display the exact error by accessing $v.emaill